# showing lunar and solar ephemerides in Emacs agenda

Tags: init-file, org-agenda, calendar

Is there a way to show the calendar functions for phases of the moon? I know it's an inbuilt function of Emacs, but I have never seen it pop up in my agenda.

Thank you,

EG

Comment: I've suggested a question title change because it looked you were asking only for eclipses while body talks about moon phases. Ephemerides covers both.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're expecting out of it. On a given date agenda, pressing <kbd>M</kbd> will show you all the relevant info about moon ephemerides.

If you want it inside your, say, daily agenda you'll have to add them as sexps in any of your agenda files. Note that there shouldn't be any subtree indentation before `%%`

```
* Moon phases
%%(my-moon-phases-function)
```

Where `my-moon-phases-function` returns a string with the phase for a given day  getting the info from `lunar.el`

There is a detailed howto in the org hacks page, [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#org0b31737). A sunrise/sunset snippet is also shown in that page.

It doesn't tell how to show eclipses, but if you know how to find such info, it'll be easily adaptable using these clues as well.